# TypeError: Int' object is not callable when calling Bert methods for producing embeddings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

I have the following code and I obtain 'TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable'(in new_time) but I dont understand why. I wrote it based on this tutorial
https://jalammar.github.io/a-visual-guide-to-using-bert-for-the-first-time/  and
https://github.com/getalp/Flaubert

My code :

```
#torch == 1.8.1
#numpy == 1.20.2
#pandas == 1.0.3
#transformers == 4.6.1


from transformers import logging
logging.set_verbosity_warning()

import numpy as np
import torch
from transformers import FlaubertModel, FlaubertTokenizer

language_model_dir = 'flaubert/flaubert_small_cased' # version > 2.0.0
flaubert, info = FlaubertModel.from_pretrained(language_model_dir, output_loading_info=True)
flaubert_tokenizer = FlaubertTokenizer.from_pretrained(language_model_dir)

# f_verbatim is a " <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>", table of sentences
tokenized = f_verbatim.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, padding=True, truncation=True))) 
#print(tokenized)

#Padding
max_len = 0
for i in tokenized.values:
    if len(i) > max_len:
        max_len = len(i)
padded = np.array([i + [0] * (max_len - len(i)) for i in tokenized.values])
# set data to tensor format
input_ids = torch.tensor(padded)
print(type(input_ids)) #<class 'torch.Tensor'>

attention_mask = np.where(padded != 0, 1, 0)
print(type(attention_mask))  #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

# this line is causing the error
hidden_state = flaubert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
```

Error :  #Stacktrace
​

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-8d53b819c31a> in <module>
      1 print(flaubert)
----> 2 hidden_state = flaubert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)

~\Anaconda3\envs\bert\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~\Anaconda3\envs\bert\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\flaubert\modeling_flaubert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, langs, token_type_ids, position_ids, lengths, cache, head_mask, inputs_embeds, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    195 
    196         # generate masks
--> 197         mask, attn_mask = get_masks(slen, lengths, self.causal, padding_mask=attention_mask)
    198         # if self.is_decoder and src_enc is not None:
    199         #     src_mask = torch.arange(src_len.max(), dtype=torch.long, device=lengths.device) < src_len[:, None]

~\Anaconda3\envs\bert\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\xlm\modeling_xlm.py in get_masks(slen, lengths, causal, padding_mask)
    104 
    105     # sanity check
--> 106     assert mask.size() == (bs, slen)
    107     assert causal is False or attn_mask.size() == (bs, slen, slen)
    108 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

As I understand, the problem is due to a missing comma but I cannot figure it out.
printing "flaubert" fucntion give :

```
(FlaubertModel(
  (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 512)
  (embeddings): Embedding(68729, 512, padding_idx=2)
  (layer_norm_emb): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
  (attentions): ModuleList(
    (0): MultiHeadAttention(
      (q_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (k_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (v_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (out_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (1): MultiHeadAttention(
      (q_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (k_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (v_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (out_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (2): MultiHeadAttention(
      (q_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (k_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (v_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (out_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (3): MultiHeadAttention(
      (q_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (k_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (v_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (out_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (4): MultiHeadAttention(
      (q_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (k_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (v_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (out_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (5): MultiHeadAttention(
      (q_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (k_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (v_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (out_lin): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
  )
  (layer_norm1): ModuleList(
    (0): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (3): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (4): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (5): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
  (ffns): ModuleList(
    (0): TransformerFFN(
      (lin1): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
      (lin2): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (1): TransformerFFN(
      (lin1): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
      (lin2): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (2): TransformerFFN(
      (lin1): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
      (lin2): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (3): TransformerFFN(
      (lin1): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
      (lin2): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (4): TransformerFFN(
      (lin1): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
      (lin2): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
    (5): TransformerFFN(
      (lin1): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
      (lin2): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
    )
  )
  (layer_norm2): ModuleList(
    (0): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (3): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (4): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
    (5): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
), {'missing_keys': [], 'unexpected_keys': ['pred_layer.proj.bias', 'pred_layer.proj.weight'], 'error_msgs': []})
```

f_verbatim look likes this :

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0      Dans le cadre de l’ATEX, il y a certains types de départ moteur qu’on va mesurer la température de pot du moteur et en cas d’anomalie il faut absolument couper le moteur. 
1      moi ce qui me dérange. C’est quand on a des enfants en bas âge. C’est dangereux, c’est trop facile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
2      par rapport à une… enfin, à ce qui existe actuellement, si on parle du Tesys U… Enfin, sur Canopen, par exemple.                                                                                                                                                                       
3      Je ne verrais pas ça pour une machine, on va dire, une application. Ce serait pour plusieurs machines.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
4      Spécifique : Pas n’importe qui pourrait le prendre
```

attention_mask look like this :

```
tensor([[  0, 156,  20,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 253,  45,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,  38, 243,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        ...,
        [  0, 141, 104,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,  59, 178,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 141, 432,  ...,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

input_ids like this :

```
[[0 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 ... 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: First thing to do is put `print (flaubert)` before the line that is giving trouble. That may be enough to tell you want is wrong but if it isn't then add what you see to your question.

Comment: @BoarGules I did it , it seems it takes a dictionnary as input (not sure maybe redaing badly the list of output of the function)

Comment: Add `, return_tensors="pt"` in addition to your `, padding=True, truncation=True` in the tokenizer statement above -> you readily get the tensors instead of lists or arrays, so the .size() can later be used by the model.
[For my bert model at least, this helped me solve the same/similar error]

Answer (score 1):

This is because `from_pretrained` function gives you a tuple of model and dictionary and you did not separate them. Modify you code like this (add another variable):

```
flaubert, info = FlaubertModel.from_pretrained(language_model_dir, output_loading_info=True)
```

You have set `output_loading_info` to True. So it also return a dictionary. If you don't specify assignment variable, it will pass a tuple (model,dictionary) to `flaubert` variable. And since `falubert` is a tuple, you can not execute it.

UPDATE: `attention_mask` is a numpy array, but your model expects a torch tensor. So, convert it to a torch tensor before passing it to your model.

```
attention_mask = torch.from_numpy(attention_mask)
hidden_state = flaubert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will checked your suggestion.

Comment: I changed but I am getting this error now : ~\Anaconda3\envs\bert\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\xlm\modeling_xlm.py in get_masks(slen, lengths, causal, padding_mask)
    104 
    105     # sanity check
--> 106     assert mask.size() == (bs, slen)
    107     assert causal is False or attn_mask.size() == (bs, slen, slen)
    108 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: the same line which give me : tuple error :
 print(flaubert)  ----> 2 hidden_state = flaubert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)

Comment: It's a completely different error. It's because type of ``attention_mask`` which is ``numpy.ndarray``. And ndarray give its' size as attribute not as a method. So it will be true to call ``mask.size`` instead of ``mask.size()``. But it is a built-in function. It seems that ``flaubert`` expects another type for ``attention_mask`` which has ``.size()`` method, not an ndarray.

Comment: Actually it expects a torch tensor, but you have passed mask as a numpy array. First convert ``mask_attention`` to a torch tensor, then pass it to the function. Use ``attention_mask=torch.from_numpy(attention_mask)``